Slow booting with a black screen and shows booting in insecure mode
Slow booting with a black screen and shows booting in insecure mode.
[21783.700345] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! _mmc_poll_for_busy
[21784.760283] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! _mmc_poll_for_busy


Black screen
Shows booting in insecure mode
When I turn off my system it shows "card stuck being busy" and then turns off.
I haven't inserted any external storage device.
I have tried to update the kernel versions, but it didn't get fixed.


All your issues may be related to this one message (booting in insecure mode).
Even though Ubuntu has the validation disable it "is seen" by BIOS (UEFI) as signed because of shim-signed package. Shim package while Ubuntu is booting checks what is the MOK state and if validation is disabled shows message "Booting in insecure mode"
